# ¿Cómo pintar linea de progreso en pbapply desde consola?

Tags: r

Habitualmente utilizo las funciones del paquete de [r](/questions/tagged/r) **pbapply** para llamadas a funciones del tipo *apply* que vayan a ser muy costosas temporalmente hablando ya que esta función alternativa pinta una barra de progreso y una predicción del tiempo restante.

Cuando ejecuto esta función llamando al script **desde línea de comandos** no se pinta la barra de progreso. La llamada que hago es una llamada clásica:`rscript MyScript.R`

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: En este sitio tienes la obligación de preguntar en castellano, si quieres formular tu pregunta en inglés está SO, si no la traduces en un tiempo se te cerrará.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

efectivamente con las opciones default en consola mediante `rscript` no se muestra la barra de progreso, esto es por como esta configurada por defecto:

> Type of the progress bar: timer ("timer"), text ("txt"), Windows
>   ("win"), TclTk ("tk"), or none ("none"). Default value is "timer"
>   progress bar with estimated remaining time when in interactive mode,
>   and "none" otherwise.

En modo interactivo se configura como "timer" y como "none" cuando no se ejecuta en modo interactivo, o sea mediante el `rscript`. La solución es configurar la barra antes de usarla para que no tome los valores default.

```
pboptions(type="timer")
```

Comment: perfecto! Esa fue la solución. Gracias Patricio

Comment: @fmjabato si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, considera marcaría como aceptada, haciendo click en el ✔️ que se encuentra a la izquierda, junto a las flechas de votación.